# Firebase Emulator Functions and Android Emulator

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, localhost, firebase-tools

i'm new to firebase and android in general, i'm trying to use the firebase functions emulator and call a function from my android emulated app (an example found online) but i'm getting a connection error (java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:5001).

I have set up the emulator address to 0.0.0.0:5001 and seems to work fine. This is what is see in the console:

functions[addNumbers]: http function initialized (http://0.0.0.0:5001/.....)
The screenshot attached here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQRgH.png)

The file firebase.json looks like this:

```
{  
  "functions": {
  "predeploy": [
  "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
  "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  ] 
},
"emulators": {
"functions": {
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port":5001
  }
}
}
```

The android code is the following:

```
mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
mFunctions.useFunctionsEmulator( "http://localhost:5001" );
```

And the call to the function looks like this:

```
return mFunctions
       .getHttpsCallable("addNumbers")
       .call(data)
       .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Integer>() {
       @Override
          public Integer then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
          Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) task.getResult().getData();
          return (Integer) result.get("operationResult");
       }
});
```

If i change the useFunctionsEmulator parameter and set 10.0.2.2:5001 i get a different error (NOT_FOUND)